# Why do lion, tiger, panther, and leopard have female forms (lioness, tigress, pantheress, leopardess), but jaguar, puma, cheetah, and cougar don't?

Tags: animals, feminine

Lion, tiger, panther, and leopard have female forms: lioness, tigress, pantheress, leopardess, but jaguar, puma, cheetah, and cougar don't.

Jagress? Pumess? Cheetess? Cougress? Those aren't words.

Is there any explanation as to why those two sets are different?

Comment: Actually ***pantheress*** exist:  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pantheress

Comment: A **she-cougar**?

Comment: It doesn't look like enough research was done here.

Comment: Please avoid making edits that invalidate existing answers. In this case, there is already an answer addressing the "pantheress" part of your question that you got wrong.

Comment: And please don’t put language into posts to *say* that they were edited.

Comment: Are you serious? YOU re-edited my post to make it look like I was invalidating existing answers. I expressly included an acknowledgment to avoid that, which you censored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly because *-ess* was not productive in English for animals, only for humans. The OED says (s.v. *-ess*): "In English the suffix is not used to form feminines of names of animals: lioness, tigress being adoptions from French".

This is not entirely correct: its own account of the etymology of *pantheress* and *leopardess* does not mention a French origin; but it is clearly mostly true.

The other point, connected with this, is to do with the age of the word in English.
All the words which have an *-ess* form were in English before 1400, and apart from *pantheress*, their feminine forms were recorded by 1611.

According to the OED:

- Lion: c825 Lioness: 1300s
- Tiger: c1000 Tigress: 1611
- Leopard: c1330  Leopardess: 1567
- Panther: (OE) Pantheress: 1831

In contrast:

- Jaguar: 1604
- Cougar: 1774

Comment: 'Mostly because -ess was not productive in English for animals, only for humans' pushes the question deeper without fully answering it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Almost all answers to "why" questions about language other than "Because that's the way it is" do that.

Comment: That's why not many are on-topic on ELU, as they give rise to disguised variants of  'that's the way it is'. You add valuable and relevant analysis here though.

Answer (score 0):

Pantheress is a word according to M-W. It is much more common to hear “female panther” or “female cougar”.

Only “lioness” is in common usage. There is no law dictating why it is so, but most likely because the species has captivated Western civilization like no other big cat.

Comment: Perhaps “lioness” is more widely used because of the visual and behavioral differences between lionesses and (male) lions.  But that leaves the question: why aren’t there female forms for “cardinal” (the bird) and “elephant”? … … … … … … … … … And a riddle: “Why can you walk through a female egret?”

Comment: Because a female egret is an egress? @Scott

Comment: I suppose I should acknowledge [Piers Anthony](http://elizabethtwist.blogspot.com/2012/04/this-way-to-egress.html?showComment=1333634009805#c6129629122376244293) as the source of the ‘‘egress’’ pun.